# CVS Automation: How do I detect a local file has been deleted so as to trigger a cvs remove?

Tags: version-control, automation, cvs

I'm looking to automate the backup of a Windows XP file structure (a wiki) into CVS.
Through repeated calls to *cvs commit* and *cvs add* I can identify and commit changed files and newly added files, but I can't see a cvs command that would let me know a local file has been deleted.

One possibility would be to update a parallel file structure with the latest files from the repository and then remove those files that only appear in second structure, but I was hoping there was a more efficient solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to run cvs update, and parse the results. It will tell you which files have been added, removed, etc. Then you can use those to run the right commands. A warning: CVS isn't easy to automate, because it's not very consistent with its messages. But you'll get it working eventually.

Answer (score 3):

You could do a

```
cvs -nq update
```

and look for lines like

```
cvs update: warning: SourceControlledFile.xml was lost
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

I am using CVSNT 2.5.05 on Windows XP. Discovered that if you just run

```
cvs remove -R
```

on a directory (without the `-f` param) it will only remove files that are actually missing from the file system. For files that are still there, it will only throw out a message which your automation script can safely ignore.

This is great for use outside of scripts too. Now I can just run:

```
cvs -nq update | findstr /C:"U "
```

Check to make sure these are all actually files I want removed, then on same dir run:

```
cvs remove -R
```

---

I had success on Windows XP with CVSNT using

```
cvs -nq update | findstr /C:"U "
```

Which produces results like this:

```
U file1.cs
U file2_23.cs
U directory_1/Reports/test.rpt
```

Of coures, this idea (and the other ideas) only work for automation if there is no chance that these files are actually files someone added to the repository since you last updated your working copy.

I personally use this cmd just to create a list of files I need to manually do a `cvs remove` on before doing a commit.